# How do I get the index of an object in an NSArray using string value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get the index of an object within the NSMutableArray of categories.

The category object has an attribute "category_title" and I want to be able to get the index by passing the value of category_title.

I have looked through the docs and can't find a simple way to go about this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`NSArray` does not guarantee that you can only store one copy of a given object, so you have to make sure that you handle that yourself (or use `NSOrderedSet`).

That said, there are a couple approaches here.  If your category objects implement `isEqual:` to match category_title, then you can just use `-indexOfObject:`.

If you can't do that (because the category objects use a different definition of equality), use `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:`.  It takes a block in which you can do whatever test you want to define your "test" - in this case, testing `category_title` string equality.

Note that these are all declared for `NSArray`, so you won't see them if you are only looking at the `NSMutableArray` header/documentation.

EDIT: Code sample.  This assumes objects of class `CASCategory` with an `NSString` property `categoryTitle` (I can't bring myself to put underscores in an ivar name :-):

```
    CASCategory *cat1 = [[CASCategory alloc] init];
    [cat1 setCategoryTitle:@"foo"];
    CASCategory *cat2 = [[CASCategory alloc] init];
    [cat2 setCategoryTitle:@"bar"];
    CASCategory *cat3 = [[CASCategory alloc] init];
    [cat3 setCategoryTitle:@"baz"];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cat1, cat2, cat3, nil];
    [cat1 release];
    [cat2 release];
    [cat3 release];

    NSUInteger barIndex = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([[(CASCategory *)obj categoryTitle] isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {
            *stop = YES;
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];

    if (barIndex != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"The title of category at index %lu is %@", barIndex, [[array objectAtIndex:barIndex] categoryTitle]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you post a snippet of how to use indexOfObjectPassingTest?

Comment: Ok that was very much appreciated and did exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: Note that if the array happens to be nil, this test will pass with an index of zero.

Comment: Note: it's actually unnecessary to set *stop = YES; as it'll be automatically stoped if you return YES;

"The block returns a Boolean value that indicates whether obj passed the test. Returning YES will stop further processing of the array." as stated in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest: .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I understand the question but something like this might work (assuming the Mutable Array contains objects of Class "Category"):

```
int indx;
bool chk;
for (Category *aCategory in theArray) 
{
    chk = ([[aCategory category_title] isEqualToString:@"valOfCategoryTitle"])
    if ( chk )
        indx = [theArray indexOfObject:aCategory];
}
```

Comment: Quite correct in principle (and probably the thing to do if you need to support iOS < 4), but for more modern systems, you ought to consider the block-based approach.

Comment: Yea blocks are good but just trying to keep it simple to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks. Seeing both this answer and the block-based answer by Conrad Shultz is enlightening.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code much more simpler:-

```
int f = [yourArray indexOfObject:@"yourString"];
```

Comment: The OP wants to search an array of custom objects, not an array of strings.

Comment: you can search an object like this way also and i have implemented for strings and objects

Comment: Sure, but it requires that -isEqual: of the custom class do a string-equality check against, in the OP's case, category_title.  This is not indicated in the question, so this solution, as written, won't generally work.