# How to delete duplicate cbperipheal devices(BLE) from array having different CBPeripheral id but same identifier in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

I have 3 objects in an array but first two are same identifier (same device) so i need to remove any one from array.Can anyone help me out.

Comment: So are you asking help to remove an element from an array?

Comment: Why not use a `NSDictionary` with the UUID as a key? Why before adding the peripheral into the array, check before hand if it's already present and if yes replace it or do not add it?

Comment: "<CBPeripheral: 0x15e3d3a0, identifier = AEFE6758-D51B-1B7F-3AE5-C9F23D2F4556, name = Polar H7 B6E94D16, state = disconnecting>",
    "<CBPeripheral: 0x15f5f980, identifier = 1990FC93-CBE4-CAFD-3D10-0A5C98430683, name = HRM, state = disconnected>",
    "<CBPeripheral: 0x1704d020, identifier = 1990FC93-CBE4-CAFD-3D10-0A5C98430683, name = HRM, state = disconnected>"

Comment: i did this but couldnt help

Comment: HRM have different CBPeripheal id but have same identifier how can i delete one HRM

Comment: @Larme I agree with you

Comment: You can use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` is you want to keep using a `NSMutableArray` (see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136785/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-an-object-in-an-nsarray-using-string-value), if found, replace the object with `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`

Comment: Why are you getting duplicates?  Are you specifiying `nil` for the service when scanning for peripherals?  If so, you should specify the service that you want; not only will you avoid the duplicates it is more efficient

Comment: i did this ...provided services still it sometimes scan duplicate value

Comment: and i disconnect the devices but it will not comes under scanning again.is anyone facing this issue?

Comment: you want to delete duplicate element?

Answer (score 1):

Use CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey in option to remove the duplication of devices.

```
NSDictionary *scanOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:scanOptions];
```

And you have your device UUID then use it in place of nil by giving in NSArray format

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
```